# How do you set all values in a pandas data frame at once if you multiply two other data frames to produce it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I want to take two data frames and multiply them together to make a third one.

Say I have

```
            HI   BYE  HE  HER   
Date                                                   
2011-01-10  2     2    2   2 
2011-01-13  2     2    2   2    
2011-01-13  2     2    2   2   
2011-01-26  2     2    2   2
```

and

```
            BRO  CHICK DUDE MAN   
Date                                                   
2011-01-10  2     2    2     2 
2011-01-13  2     2    2     2    
2011-01-13  2     2    2     2   
2011-01-26  2     2    2     2
```

and I want,

```
            MY  NAME  IS    SLIM_SHADY   
Date                                                   
2011-01-10  4     4    4     4 
2011-01-13  4     4    4     4    
2011-01-13  4     4    4     4   
2011-01-26  4     4    4     4
```

How do I do this in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to `np.array` using `.values` and perform element-wise multiplication.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df1.values * df2.values,
         index=df1.index, columns="MY NAME IS SLIM_SHADY".split())
print(df)
            MY  NAME  IS  SLIM_SHADY
Date                                
2011-01-10   4     4   4           4
2011-01-13   4     4   4           4
2011-01-13   4     4   4           4
2011-01-26   4     4   4           4
```

---

Another method would be to rename indexes, and then call `df.mul`:

```
df2.columns = df1.columns  # could also add df2.index = df1.index for security
df = df1.mul(df2)
df.columns="MY NAME IS SLIM_SHADY".split()

print(df)
            MY  NAME  IS  SLIM_SHADY
Date                                
2011-01-10   4     4   4           4
2011-01-13   4     4   4           4
2011-01-13   4     4   4           4
2011-01-26   4     4   4           4
```

Comment: I prefer the first one. You?

Comment: @dirtysocks45 Same, it's much cleaner than the second.

Comment: Do you mind checking my other question on vectorization? My last comment on the accepted answer has a question.

Comment: @dirtysocks45 I took a look at piR's solution, but it went over my head. I'll let him handle it. Sorry about that.

Comment: He is the Pandas and Numpy God